# Excel - Highlight in number order

Tags: excel, formula, highlight

I have an excel document and would like to highlight numbers in order of their amount. If there is 10 in B2, 9 in B3 and 8 in B4 then it would highlight B2 in red, as it is highest, B3 in orange, and B4 in yellow.
The only way I can see to do this is to use =IFS as follows :
=IFS(B4B3,"Top",[all the other outcomes]
This would display where they are but as far as I can see there is no way to highlight other cells using formulas. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just a simple matter of conditional formatting which you'll find in the main ribbon (on top). Highlight the range you wish to include and select the conditional formatting option. You'll see the numbers highlight real-time as you hover through the selections. Just like this:

[image: See here:]

Comment: Ok! Thank you! This helped a lot :)